# TravisCI - Is it possible to start docker service and expect mysql to work?

Tags: mysql, docker, travis-ci

I am new to using Travis CI and i am trying to use the MySQL database along with a docker container. I am able to start docker service and run my container or I am able to connect to mysql. But I am not able to do both.

**MySQL - Works**

```
language: bash

sudo: required

before_script:
- "mysql -e 'create database atg_core;'"
- "mysql -e 'create database atg_ca;'"

script:
- "mysql -e 'show databases;'"
```

**Docker - Works**

```
sudo: required

language: bash

services:
  - docker

install:
  - docker pull asnagaraj/oracle-atg-11.1:v4

script:
  - docker run -v $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR:/workspace/test-atg-module asnagaraj/oracle-atg-11.1:v4 /bin/bash -c ". ~/.bash_profile; cd /workspace/test-atg-module;  gradle --stacktrace gATGM; "
```

**Combined - Doesnt Work**

```
sudo: required

language: bash

services:
  - docker

install:
  - docker pull asnagaraj/oracle-atg-11.1:v4

before_script:
  - "mysql -e 'create database atg_core;'"
  - "mysql -e 'create database atg_ca;'"

script:
  - docker run --net="host" -v $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR:/workspace/test-atg-module asnagaraj/oracle-atg-11.1:v4 /bin/bash -c ". ~/.bash_profile; cd /workspace/test-atg-module;  gradle --stacktrace gATGM; telnet localhost 3306; telnet 127.0.0.1 3306"
```

I am not even expecting the telnet to work, even the **mysql -e create** commands fail..

Please help.

-Naga

Answer (score 0):

Under the services section of you travis.yml file you will have to let travis know that you are using mysql as such:

```
services:
  - mysql
```

as taken from https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MySQL

So your **services** section will become:

```
services:
  -docker
  -mysql
```